# How to configure NGINX routes?

Tags: nginx, docker

I have 5 lamp containers (`tutum/lamp`) with mounted ports as follows:

```
127.0.0.1:81:80
127.0.0.1:82:80
127.0.0.1:83:80
127.0.0.1:84:80
127.0.0.1:85:80
```

What I would like to do is put an NGINX in front of them so that it redirects to the appropriate containers depending on the URL. For example, let's assume that the host IP is `12.45.5.113`. Then, when I visit `12.45.5.113/c1/` I want to get redirected to home page of container `127.0.0.1:81:80`, when I visit `12.45.5.113/c2/` I want to get redirected to home page of container `127.0.0.1:82:80` and so on so forth.

How should the NGINX configuration look like? Should I installed NGINX on the host with `apt-get install` or it could be possible to install it as a additional container too?

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest approach is to launch nginx in container.

```
docker run --port 80:80 --link c1 ... --link cn ... nginx
```

with config like (can be mounted from host by `--volume` argument to `docker run`):

```
{
   listen 80;
   location /c1/ {
      proxy_pass http://c1;
   }

   ...
   location /cn/ {
      proxy_pass http://cn;
   }
}
```

this way it will redirect all request as you wish using `Docker` container linking mechanism (all request will be routed through `bridge` network).

For more information check Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#/connect-with-the-linking-system

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I have a last question though: I have noticed that `echo 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` doesn't contain the middle-path e.g. `/c1/`, After some searching, I found that a` Rewrite Rule` on the NGINX level could do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, please give some example because I don't know what you are asking about.